# Bind and arrow context

Tags: javascript, bind, arrow-functions

Why this bouth cases are not working? So I'm not so clear understand the logic of bind and arrow funcs, but I study them already. It would be great if you explaine me my problems on these cases.

Thank you

First case:

```
    const obj = {
        a: 42,
        say:  function() {

            console.log(this.a);

        }
    };

    obj.say.bind(obj); // empty result
```

Second case:

```
        const obj = {
            a: 42,
            say:  () => {

                console.log(this.a); //

            }
        };

        obj.say(); // undefined
```

Comment: arrow functions don't have their own `this` and `arguments`, they borrow the same form enclosing context.\

Comment: First should work if you write `obj.say.bind(obj)();`.

Comment: @31piy can you explaine, please, the second case?